# How do I stop wordpress redirecting from subdomain to primary?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I want to have 2 versions of the site. A testing/development version, and a public, live version. When I try to go to dev.mysite.com, it just redirects to www.mysite.com.

I completely deleted the .htaccess files and that did nothing, so it must be somewhere in wordpress's files. Has anyone ever done this before? There's so many includes in the core files, I'm getting lost.

It's fine if the site uses the same database, I just want to be able to essentially have a "breakable" site that the general users can't see.

Does anybody know where I would need to make a change to keep it from redirecting?

Comment: having both sites pointing to the same database is not ok. wordpress stores the site url in the database, that can be the reason of your redirect, a lot of code uses this stored url for redirects and link formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these 2 lines in your `wp-config.php`:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://dev.mysite.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://dev.mysite.com');
```

Comment: That didn't work. I added it to the config file that resides on the subdomain. I also tried deleting the .htaccess file in case that was doing it. Does it matter where in the config file I add it? I tried it in multiple places, but no luck.

Comment: Also try changing `wp-options` table with similar option names (home and siteurl)

Comment: Your reference to "options" gave me an idea. So I just duplicated the database and changed the home and siteurl values to dev.mysite.com  Thank you for pointing me in the right direction :)